# Is there a way to verify a Google Chrome tab URL by using UI-Automator Android?

Tags: google-chrome, android-uiautomator

I have tried a couple of options but I am unable to test the Google Chrome tab url's by android ui-automator. Could someone please help me out here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's assume on click of a button you're trying to navigate to "https://www.abcd.com/xyz". 
(This URL is not valid. This is just a sample)

Steps to follow:

1. **Initialise UiSelector and UiDevice in your test class** : 
   private val select = UiSelector() 
   private val device =
   UiDevice.getInstance(InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation())
2. **Click on the button** : onView(withId(id)).perform(click())
3. **Find the resource id** : 
    val urlBar = device.findObject(select.resourceId("com.android.chrome:id/url_bar"))
4. **Assert the Navigation** : assert(urlBar.text.contains("xyz"))

Comment: did not work for me the url bar is only showing the host name.  The assert fails, but if I click on the info in the more menu and have it open in Chrome App, it takes me to the right url.